# Approximation of $\frac{f(x_0+h)+f(x_0-h)}{2}-f(x_0)$ for $h\rightarrow 0$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

As the title says, I'm interested of a way to describe "how far is the value of $f$ at a point from the average of the two values from its both sides, as the distance tends to zero".
I think, from manual checking, that this expression is of the same order of magnitude as $h^2$. Therefore, in an attempt to give a formula that captures the concept of "measuring diatance from average", I thought about the following definition:
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\left [ \frac{1}{h^2}\left ( \frac{f(x_0+h)+f(x_0-h)}{2}-f(x_0)\right ) \right ]$$
I've tried to prove that this equals to $f''(x)$ (I feel like the second derivative should have something to do with it), and got pretty close:

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\left [ \frac{1}{h^2}\left ( \frac{f(x_0+h)+f(x_0-h)}{2}-f(x_0)\right ) \right ]=
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\left [ \frac{1}{2h}\left ( \frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}-\frac{f(x_0)-f(x_0-h)}{h}\right ) \right ]=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\left ( \frac{( f'(x_0+c_h^1)-f'(x_0-c_h^2) }{2h}\right )$$
for some midvalues $c_h^1, c_h^2\in (0,h)$.
The last expression "feels" like the second derivative but the lack of freedom in choosing those midvalues kind of ruins that.

Do you have any idea about a nice way to assign this intuitive meaning a numeric value, preferably using the second derivative (though it detracts from the generality...)? Does my way seem right?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Higher-order_differences

Comment: Hint: use l'Hopital's rule and you will indeed get $f''(x_0)$.  (Though be careful: the existence of the limit is not sufficient to show $f''(x_0)$ exists.  A counterexample would be $f(x) = x^{1/3}$ at $x_0 = 0$.  Another counterexample which is even continuously differentiable at $x_0 = 0$ would be $f(x) = x^{5/3}$.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reputation to comment. But what you've written in the question is a difference - so it's not the average value. To answer your question literally, the answer is $-f(x_0)$

Comment: Oops, you're right. The power of habit, I guess...

Comment: Yay, I can comment on my own answer... I would do a Taylor series expansion for each expression. You'll see the first term is $f(x_0)$, the thing you're subtracting off. The other terms will either add or exactly cancel do to the alternating signature. So whatever is left over is your answer.

Comment: @AndySpencer There are other ways to get more reputation to comment, such as asking, answering and accepting questions which get votes. You might get flagged for this - remember that Math SE (unfortunately) has a strict site policy.

Answer (score 0):

Observe $$\frac{ f(x-h)+2f(x)+f(x+h}{h^2} = \frac{\frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h}-\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}}{h}$$ is the difference quotient of two difference quotients. Intuitively, the expression is looking at the "rate of change of the rate of change" and should somehow quantify the information of the second derivative when $h \to 0$. In turns out that the limit is a generalization of the second derivative called the **second symmetric derivative**, and it exists even when the second derivative does not.